# Mandatory flag with a message command line args

Tags: powershell, parameters

I cannot seem to figure out if this is possible or not. I want to validate the command line args if they are missing args print a pretty message.

For example

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="User Name must be specified.")]
[string]$userName
)
```

Now if I run my script from the command line, it still prints out this ugly red message at the bottom:

> Missing an argument for parameter 'userName'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.

How do I get it to print `HelpMessage`? Or better yet, call my own method with the missing param.

Comment: The user will not see the `HelpMessage` unless they type in `!?` **(Type !? for Help.)**

Comment: you could take the mandatory flag off of the parameter. Then check it. If it is null or empty do a `Read-Host` (Jeff Zeitlin's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique I’ve used for this is to *not* make the parameter `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]`, but instead to set a default value that is effectively the procedure to call if the parameter is omitted:

```
param (
    $foo = (Read-Host "You must supply a foo! Enter foo value:")
)
```